# Gas soldering iron - Yellow flame only

Tags: soldering-iron-station

My gas soldering iron now emits a yellow flame, and does not light internally. What is the problem and what can I do to rectify it? It has been filled using 100% butane gas and is only 6 months old.

Link to model datasheet
http://doc.ferm.com/Servotool/documents/SGM6013%20Ma%20%200806-06.pdf

Comment: Yellow usually means not enough oxygen.  Check that the air holes are clear.

Comment: Maybe your catalyst is broken/used up ? Mine is a different brand but looks almost identical. Do you get a yellow flame when all the bits that go on the "hot" part are removed ? A yellow flame is indeed an indication that there is not enough air entering in the burner. The flame should be blue. Only then should you mount all the other bits including the catalyst (the bit that should glow orange after you interrupt the flame.

Answer (score 1):

They usually depend on a small metallic mesh catalyst to achieve an efficient burn.  It sounds like your catalyst is missing, damaged or inoperative, e.g. due to being coated in soot.  Or it's not getting enough oxygen; check the inlets for blockages.

Edit: googling for "gas soldering iron catalyst" reveals a litany of woes that people have suffered with these things.

Answer (score 1):

There is usually a sleeve between gas cylinder and burner, which you can rotate to open a hole : this allows air to pre-mix with the gas for a blue flame, or close for a yellow flame.

I can see it in the linked advert : it opens four holes. Ensure they are open by rotating the sleeve (exercise caution if the sleeve is hot!) The advert calls this part 8 : Guard but does not mention whether or not it can rotate.